# return unformatted content in encosing shortcode

Tags: shortcode, formatting

I've written a little shortcode, following [basic](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) instructions on Wordpress Codex:

```
function myshortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        ...,
    ), $atts ) );
    return some_html _code_here . $content;
}
```

When I put

```
[myshortcode]
this 
is 
a 
test
content
[/myshortcode]
```

in a post, I obtain the following output:

```
this <br />
is <br />
a <br />
test <br />
content <br />
```

How can I avoid the inserting of br / tags?

Comment: That's normal, the text would all be on one line otherwise when displayed(which is not how you've formatted it in the editor - ie. each word is on a new line). If you don't want newlines, don't create them in the editor.

Comment: Anyway this can be a problem, as described in http://betterwp.net/17-protect-shortcodes-from-wpautop-and-the-likes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<br />` tags are being added to the content by the `wpautop()` function. If you run your shortcode before it runs they will not be there. It is added in `\wp-includes\default-filters.php` with the default priority of `10`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myshortcode', 1 );

function myshortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return $content;
}
```

[wpautop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) can also add other markup besides `<br />` tags.

Comment: I obtain a `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myshortcode' not found or invalid function name` message.

Comment: The second argument in [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) has to match the name of your shortcode function exactly. Copy the function name you used and paste it over the `myshortcode` in that line.

Comment: I have to use `do_shortcode` in place of `myshortcode` (which is the exact name of the handler function). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
function myshortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return strip_tags($content,'br');
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode');
```

But I am unclear why you are you adding newlines in the first place if you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myshortcode_callback' );

function myshortcode_callback( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return str_replace( '<br />', '', $content );
}
```

by simply removing the `<br />` tags from the output. If you want to strip all HTML tags, you can use `strip_tags()` instead.